# exporting an environment variable from a bash script to a tcsh shell

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables, tcsh

I run bash scripts from tcsh shells.    I want to set an environment variable in the tcsh shell from a bash script.

The method of doing this, if your parent shell is bash is to source a file,
i.e., if I have a file called `dog` that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
myEnv=foo
export $myEnv
```

then from a bash shell, the command

```
. dog
```

will as expected create an envi
    source dog

then nothing happens.   Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do?

thanks!

Comment: What does "will as expected create an envi source dog" mean in English?

Comment: Sorry, that was a  typo.    Please see my response to @Serg below.   My problem is that I can't find any way to communicate from within a bash script to the parent shell that is running in my xterm.   All I need to do is to somehow create an environment variable in the parent tcsh shell from within a bash script.    Seems like it should be really easy, rather than impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
export myEnv
```

not

```
export $myEnv
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Gunnar already noted,  `export` will make the variable available only to that instance of bash shell and its child processes. In addition `tcsh` and `bash` syntax differ when it comes to variables.

I would suggest you  set a variable in the syntax familiar to `tcsh`

```
eagle:~/sergrep> cat var_file.txt
setenv foo "TEST"
eagle:~/sergrep> source var_file.txt
eagle:~/sergrep> echo $foo
TEST
```

Comment: What you suggested @Serg works fine from `tcsh`.   But my problem is that I need to run the  source command from inside a `bash` script.     That is somehow I have to make `bash` talk to my parent `tcsh` shell.    When I run your `var_file.txt` from with a bash script, with the command `. var_file.txt`   it returns an error saying that it can't find setenv.   That's the essence of my problem.

Comment: @LeoSimon talking to the parent shell is exactly the problem. To the best of my knowledge , there's no way to communicate a variable back to parent. May i ask what is the purpose of such behavior ? Is spawning a child tcsh from script an option ? export will make variables available to children

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if I could spawn a child tcsh script from within a bash script I'd be fine.     The script would do exactly what you said above, i.e., simply `setenv foo "TEST"`.    The reason I want to do this that I want my latex scripts to read an environment variable.   This variable has a default value.    I have a complicated bash script, within which I sometimes want to specify a modified value for this environment variable.   That's why I need to do a `setenv` from within the bash script.  Hope this is clear enough?